# I made a mistake in a simple JS program, but I don't know why it's wrong

Tags: javascript

The program is supposed to take string and print it's reverse in the console:

```
var string = "squirrels";
reverseString = "";
for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
reverseString[i] = string[string.length - 1 - i];
}
console.log(reverseString);
```

If instead I declare reverse as an empty array, and instead use

```
console.log(reverseString.join(""));
```

then the code works fine - but whats wrong with the original code?

Comment: use `reverseString+= string[string.length - 1 - i];`

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong is that string is not a sum of individual characters. It's still array-like object meaning that you can read its characters by their indexes but you can't change string by changing char at position specified by index.

That's why array works. You could also use concatenation instead.